# Deserializing the Json object to .NET object

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I have following JSON object returned by vatlayer api

```
{
  "success":true,
  "rates":{
    "AT":{
      "country_name":"Austria",
      "standard_rate":20,
      "reduced_rates":{
        "foodstuffs":10,
        "books":10,
        "pharmaceuticals":10,
        "passenger transport":10,
        "newspapers":10,
        "admission to cultural events":10,
        "hotels":10,
        "admission to entertainment events":10
      }
    },
    "BE":{
      "country_name":"Belgium",
      "standard_rate":21,
      "reduced_rates":{
        "restaurants":12,
        "foodstuffs":6,
        "books":6,
        "water":6,
        "pharmaceuticals":6,
        "medical":6,
        "newspapers":6,
        "hotels":6,
        "admission to cultural events":6,
        "admission to entertainment events":6
      }
    },
    "BG":{
      "country_name":"Bulgaria",
      "standard_rate":20,
      "reduced_rates":{
        "hotels":9
      }
    }
    ...more obejcts
    ...more objects
    ...more objects
}
```

I want to read data in following class

```
public class Country{
   public string ShortCode{get;set;}// AT, BE, etc are examples of shortcode
   public string Country_Name{get;set;}// Austria, Belgium etc
   public decimal Standar_Rate{get;set;}// 20 and 21 respectively
}
```

The problem is that web service is not sending data as an array of JSON objects. Rather, its sending a single object where each country short code is the key in JSON. How do I deserialize this object to `List` or `Array` of `Country` objects. I am open to using any JSON converter

Comment: Deserialize it to a `Dictionary<string,Country>` and then the `Values` of that dictionary will give you your collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just model the response like this:

```
public class Response
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Country> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
var allCountries = response.Rates.Values.ToList();
```

Note that that won't give you the `ShortCode`, which is in the dictionary key. You could get that using:

```
// Assuming the names have been fixed to be idiomatic...
var allCountries = response.Rates.Select(pair =>
    new Country {
        CountryName = pair.Value.CountryName,
        StandardRate = pair.Value.StandardRate,
        ShortCode = pair.Key
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet, I think, this would solve the problem

Comment: Shouldn't the Dictionary variable be called `Rates`? So that it would map correctly.

Comment: @Dygestor: Yes, absolutely. Apparently I'm a bit of a muppet this afternoon :)

Comment: Wont the Country.ShortCode be null

Comment: @Scrobi: Yes, but if the OP needs that, they can use the key in the dictionary instead. Will edit to clarify.